# Variable lagging in R error

Tags: r, dplyr, lag, quantmod

I am trying to lag some prices I downloaded from yahoo market but I don't want the lag to be fixed. I would like to have it where depending on another DF or Values the lag period changes.

This extracts and formats the data:

```
library("quantmod")
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
library(dplyr)

nameOfStrategy <- "GSPC MACD"

#Specify dates for downloading data, training models and running simulation
trainingStartDate = as.Date("2000-01-01")
trainingEndDate = as.Date("2010-01-01")
outofSampleStartDate = as.Date("2010-01-02")


#Download the data
symbolData <- new.env() #Make a new environment for quantmod to store data in
getSymbols("^GSPC", env = symbolData, src = "yahoo", from = trainingStartDate)
trainingData <- window(symbolData$GSPC, start = trainingStartDate, end = trainingEndDate)
testData <- window(symbolData$GSPC, start = outofSampleStartDate)
indexReturns <- Delt(Cl(window(symbolData$GSPC, start =   outofSampleStartDate)))
colnames(indexReturns) <- "GSPC Buy&Hold"
```

And this is the code I'm using to find market signals and then organize data:

```
signalB <- ifelse(MACD12$macd > MACD12$signal & lag.xts(MACD12$macd) < lag.xts(MACD12$signal),1,NA)
#If fastMA > slowMA on change go long
signalS <- ifelse(MACD12$macd < MACD12$signal & lag.xts(MACD12$macd) > lag.xts(MACD12$signal),-1,NA)

#Combines Buy and sell signals
Tsignal <- merge(signalB,signalS)

#Gets number of days---dont know when period starts but doesnt matter since we just want difference in days
Tsignal$dates =indexTZ(Tsignal)
Tsignal$dates =index(Tsignal)

#Combines Buy and Sell signal into overall signal
Tsignal$Signal <- ifelse(is.na(Tsignal$Buy),ifelse(is.na(Tsignal$Sell),NA,-1),1)
Tsignal$Tdate <- 0

#Gets 'Date' only if signal either buy or sell
Tsignal$Tdate <- ifelse(!is.na(Tsignal$Signal),Tsignal$dates,NA)

#Finds difference between the Sell sig and the last signal **** In this case it will work but future buying twice before
# selling will result in not getting returns of one of the purchases
Tsignal$lag <- ifelse(Tsignal$Signal == -1,diff(na.locf(Tsignal$Tdate)),NA)

Tsignal$lag <- ifelse(is.na(Tsignal$lag),0,Tsignal$lag)
```

Here is the problem:

```
lag(Cl(trainingData),Tsignal$lag))
#Warning message:
#In if (n == 0) return(x) :
#the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

It returns all of the prices but lagged back at a period of 0 (ie just returns the prices). While the Tsignal$lag has a lot of zero's in it there are values greater than 1 spread throughout.

I need it to return the same price during the dates where Tsignal$lag = 0 and return the price lagged back the number of periods Tsignal$lag specifies.

Currently I am using the dplyr lag function but I have tried other packages with the lag function and I get the same error. Writing this I am thinking I might have to do a 'for' function but I'm not sure, I am fairly new to R.

Thanks for your help ahead of time!

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example plz?

Answer (score 0):

Both the dplyr and stats lag functions require integers for the number of lag periods (?dplyr::lag), but your Tsignal$lag is a vector.  To remain in the xts domain, one suggestion is to use the lag values as direct index offsets to the close prices, as in

```
Cl(trainingData)[(1:nrow(trainingData))-coredata(Tsignal$lag),]
```